# Unable to start on windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

After type in user name and password, the screen shows "loading personal settings....." and then immediately log-off automatically and back to the "ctrl-alt-del to login" page. Help!

Comment: A) Have you tried logging on as a different user?  (The user profile could be corrupted)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the account you are using probably has a corrupt profile. Are you able to log in as the administrator account, rename the profile of the account you are having problems with, and try logging in again.

If you're not able to do that, you may be able to do it over the network using the admin C$ (or whatever drive letter your profiles are stored on) share, or failing that maybe booting into safe mode or from a recovery disk (something like ERD commander) and doing the same thing should work

Answer (score -2):

I'd first suggest to try this:

> If your original HD boots fine, the ghost process disrupted the MBR of
>   the new HD.
>
> Boot from a Windows 98 Startup disk with your new HD as the main HD
>   and run
>
> Fdisk /mbr

Source: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-11184-0.html?forumID=101&threadID=234192&messageID=2303642&tag=content;leftCol) (please read replies to the original thread - it worked for some people)

It is also possible that is caused by a malware.  I cannot yet add links (not enough reputation...) however here is what it's said:

> If your is like mine, it was infected
>   with malware which during a virus scan
>   & clean, the inituser.exe file was
>   somehow deleted from the syste32
>   folder.

Comment: The original poster has a problem logging in, not booting.  The login process takes place long after the MBR starts the boot process.  Malware is a possiblity, but the first suggestion is a red herring :)

Comment: @Sean Earp - You're quick to discard, thanks for the vote.  Even if your logic is correct, you may notice the users replying to the link above say that solution worked for them.

Comment: @Sean Earp - now I see you work for Ms ... for you logic may be stronger than factual evidence ... did you have a better solution?

Comment: -1 even if the asker needed to fix the mbr booting to a Win98 disk and doing a fdisk /mbr is the WRONG way to do it. You need to boot windows 2003 cd to a recovery console, and issue either FIXBOOT, or FIXMBR or both.